NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/net/http/HttpClient
About Automation Testing in android java project, using with Appium framework.
After follow Automation Testing with Appium guideline
I had:

android java project (java programming language)

include: appium framework (implementation appium library)

setup appium method

appium server started

include these testing framework also: testNG, espresso, uiautomator2


After write|run test case, it can not find class|package java.net.http.HttpClient (while other classes must be found from package java.net.http, ex.: URL, ...)

NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/net/http/HttpClient


How to resolve this issue?
package ex.jvautotest;

import android.util.Log;

import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.time.Duration;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.options.BaseOptions;

public class FirstTest {
    
static AndroidDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
        Log.d("", "SETUP ...");

        var options = new BaseOptions()
                .amend("appium:automationName", "UiAutomator2")
                .amend("appium:deviceName", "emulator-5554")
                .amend("appium:platformName", "Android")
                .amend("appium:app", "/Users/.../Desktop/app-debug.apk")
                .amend("appium:newCommandTimeout", 3600)
                .amend("appium:connectHardwareKeyboard", true);

        /// ERROR IN THIS LINE
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), options);

        Log.d("", "SETUP SUCCESS");
    }

    @Test
    public void sampleTest() throws Exception {
        try {
            Duration d = Duration.ofSeconds(10);
            // 1 - get Email, then input text
//            By usernameId = By.id("com.example.autotestsample:id/username");
            By usernameId = By.xpath(
                    "//android.widget.EditText[@resource-id=\"com.example.autotestsample:id/username\"]");
            driver.findElement(usernameId).sendKeys("user@email.com");    

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("", "Login failed");

            throw e;
        }
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}

File build.gradle:
plugins {
alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
}

android {
namespace = "ex.jvautotest"
compileSdk = 35

defaultConfig {
    applicationId = "ex.jvautotest"
    minSdk = 33
    targetSdk = 35
    versionCode = 1
    versionName = "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        isMinifyEnabled = false
        proguardFiles(
            getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
            "proguard-rules.pro"
        )
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_21
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_21
}
packaging {
    resources {
        excludes.add("META-INF/LICENSE.md")
        excludes.add("META-INF/LICENSE-notice.md")
        excludes.add("META-INF/INDEX.LIST")
        excludes.add("META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties")
        excludes.add("META-INF/DEPENDENCIES")
    }
}
}

dependencies {
//    implementation("org.openjdk:java.net:21")

implementation(libs.appcompat)
implementation(libs.material)
implementation(libs.activity)
implementation(libs.constraintlayout)
implementation(libs.androidx.room.rxjava2)
implementation(libs.androidx.room.rxjava3)
implementation(libs.androidx.room.guava)
testImplementation(libs.androidx.room.testing)
implementation(libs.androidx.room.paging)

implementation(libs.ext.appiumJavaClient)
testImplementation(libs.ext.appiumJavaClient)

implementation(libs.ext.appiumSeleniumClient)
testImplementation(libs.ext.appiumSeleniumClient)
implementation(libs.ext.appiumSeleniumHttp)
testImplementation(libs.ext.appiumSeleniumHttp)

testImplementation(libs.junit)
androidTestImplementation(libs.ext.junit)
androidTestImplementation(libs.espresso.core)
androidTestImplementation(libs.junit.jupiter)
androidTestImplementation(libs.testng)
}

libs.versions.toML file:
    [versions]
agp = "8.7.2"
appiumJavaClient = "9.3.0"
#appiumSeleniumClient = "4.26.0"

junit = "4.13.2"
junitVersion = "1.2.1"
junitJupiter = "5.11.3"
roomRuntime = "2.6.1"
testng = "7.10.2"
espressoCore = "3.6.1"

appcompat = "1.7.0"
material = "1.12.0"
activity = "1.9.3"
constraintlayout = "2.2.0"

[libraries]
androidx-room-compiler = { module = "androidx.room:room-compiler", version.ref = "roomRuntime" }
androidx-room-guava = { module = "androidx.room:room-guava", version.ref = "roomRuntime" }
androidx-room-ktx = { module = "androidx.room:room-ktx", version.ref = "roomRuntime" }
androidx-room-paging = { module = "androidx.room:room-paging", version.ref = "roomRuntime" }
androidx-room-runtime = { module = "androidx.room:room-runtime", version.ref = "roomRuntime" }
androidx-room-rxjava2 = { module = "androidx.room:room-rxjava2", version.ref = "roomRuntime" }
androidx-room-rxjava3 = { module = "androidx.room:room-rxjava3", version.ref = "roomRuntime" }
androidx-room-testing = { module = "androidx.room:room-testing", version.ref = "roomRuntime" }

ext-appiumJavaClient = { group = "io.appium", name = "java-client", version.ref = "appiumJavaClient" }

ext-appiumSeleniumClient = { group = "org.seleniumhq.selenium", name = "selenium-java", version.ref = "appiumSeleniumClient" }
ext-appiumSeleniumHttp = { group = "org.seleniumhq.selenium", name = "selenium-http", version.ref = "appiumSeleniumClient" }

junit = { group = "junit", name = "junit", version.ref = "junit" }
ext-junit = { group = "androidx.test.ext", name = "junit", version.ref = "junitVersion" }
junit-jupiter = { group = "org.junit.jupiter", name = "junit-jupiter", version.ref = "junitJupiter" }
testng = { group = "org.testng", name = "testng", version.ref = "testng" }

espresso-core = { group = "androidx.test.espresso", name = "espresso-core", version.ref = "espressoCore" }
appcompat = { group = "androidx.appcompat", name = "appcompat", version.ref = "appcompat" }
material = { group = "com.google.android.material", name = "material", version.ref = "material" }
activity = { group = "androidx.activity", name = "activity", version.ref = "activity" }
constraintlayout = { group = "androidx.constraintlayout", name = "constraintlayout", version.ref = "constraintlayout" }


[plugins]
android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }

Build system:

openjdk@21
Gradle 8.9 && 8.11




This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Sorry about that. I updated question and include config lines.

While I found another way to avoid this issue,
I still does not find out root cause of above issue Ljava/net/http/HttpClient
Before:

FAIL: I use Junit framework/package

After:

SUCCESS: I use TestNG framework/package
  package ex.jvautotest;

  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
  import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
  import org.testng.annotations.Test;

  import java.net.MalformedURLException;
  import java.net.URL;

  import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
  import io.appium.java_client.remote.options.BaseOptions;

  public class FirstTest {

  static AndroidDriver driver;

  @BeforeMethod
  public static void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
      var options = new BaseOptions()
              .amend("appium:automationName", "UiAutomator2")
              .amend("appium:deviceName", "emulator-5554")
              .amend("appium:platformName", "Android")
              .amend("appium:app", "/Users/.../app-debug.apk")
              .amend("appium:newCommandTimeout", 3600)
              .amend("appium:connectHardwareKeyboard", true);

      driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), options);
  }

  @Test
  public void sampleTest() throws Exception {
      try {
          // 1 - get Email, then input text
          By usernameId = By.id("com.example.autotestsample:id/username");
          // 2 - get Password, then input text
          By passwordId = By.id("com.example.autotestsample:id/password");
          // 3 - click SignIn, then click
          By loginId = By.id("com.example.autotestsample:id/login");

          driver.findElement(usernameId).sendKeys("user@email.com");
          driver.findElement(passwordId).sendKeys("12345");
          driver.findElement(loginId).click();
      } catch (Exception e) {
          throw e;
      }
  }

  @AfterMethod
  public static void tearDown() {
      driver.quit();
  }

}


